# Как передать name кнопки при клике с помощью классов?

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуйста. Нужно, чтобы во время клика на кнопку в соседнем div-e выводился name этой кнопки. Реализовать это нужно с помощью чистого JS и классов(если возможно), т.к у кнопок нету id, а с помощью TagName не делаю, потому что есть и другие кнопки.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="result><p><Здесь должен быть отображён name кнопки</p></div>
    <ul>
        <li class="slide"><button name="N102" class="btn"/>Button 1</li> 
        <li class="slide"><button name="N104" class="btn"/>Button 2</li> 
        <li class="slide"><button name="N106" class="btn"/>Button 3</li> 
        <li class="slide"><button name="N108" class="btn"/>Button 4</li>
    </ul>
```

У меня это работает с поиском, но с кликом по кнопке не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure JS. Все кнопки с `name`, начинающимся с `N` будут затронуты.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button.btn[name^='N']").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", e => {
    let elem = e.currentTarget;
    let name = elem.getAttribute("name");
    document.querySelector("div.result > p").innerHTML = name;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="result">
  <p>Здесь должен быть отображён name кнопки</p>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class=" slide "><button name="N102 " class="btn " />Button 1</li>
  <li class="slide "><button name="N104 " class="btn " />Button 2</li>
  <li class="slide "><button name="N106 " class="btn " />Button 3</li>
  <li class="slide "><button name="N108 " class="btn " />Button 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо брат, то что надо!

Answer (score 1):

На JQ.

```js
$(function(){
$('.btn').on('click',function(e){
   $('.result').text($(e.target).attr('name'));
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"><p><Здесь должен быть отображён name кнопки</p></div>
    <ul>
        <li class="slide"><button name="N102" class="btn"/>Button 1</li> 
        <li class="slide"><button name="N104" class="btn"/>Button 2</li> 
        <li class="slide"><button name="N106" class="btn"/>Button 3</li> 
        <li class="slide"><button name="N108" class="btn"/>Button 4</li>
    </ul>
```

На чистом JS.

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
btn[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
document.getElementsByClassName('result')[0].innerHTML = e.target.name
})
}
```

```html
<div class="result"><p>Здесь должен быть отображён name кнопки</p></div>
    <ul>
        <li class="slide"><button name="N102" class="btn"/>Button 1</li> 
        <li class="slide"><button name="N104" class="btn"/>Button 2</li> 
        <li class="slide"><button name="N106" class="btn"/>Button 3</li> 
        <li class="slide"><button name="N108" class="btn"/>Button 4</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо брат, твоё решение пока что не пробовал, но походу попробую.